# AngularJS - jSON on Date Show Certain ID

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How could i implement if today is a certain day eg) 12/11/2014 then i want to show object

```
{"id":"11th","content":"Lunch Item Here"}
```

I want to show a different lunch item everyday of the month by the data.

```
{{greeting.id}} / {{greeting.content}}

function Hello($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/data.json').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
```

Above is my Javascript file.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Many ways, a filter is something that comes to mind.

Comment: Filter works, on an ng-if for the show.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your example and example data you could do something like

```
   <div ng-show="greeting.id == '11th'">
     {{greeting.content}}
   </div>
```